# How do I specify an MVC SiteMaps Visibility attribute using Code based attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I am using the latest Nuget package of MVC SiteMap provider. We are making heavy use of code based attributes defining nodes in our site.

E.g. `[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Examination Types", ParentKey = "LookupTable", Key = "ExaminationTypeIndex")]`

We want to make use of a custom visibility provider to hide nodes from SiteMap as per [here](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced%20node%20visibility)

However we can't seem to specify node visibility attribute using Code based nodes? Is there anyway to do that. We can only specify a custom visibility provider and we would rather use the visible attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility is a custom attribute, so you need to supply it in the Attributes field in order to use it in conjunction with [MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute]. The only tricky part is that .NET attributes don't support dictionary types, so you need to supply the attributes as an escaped JSON string.

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Examination Types", ParentKey = "LookupTable", Key = "ExaminationTypeIndex", Attributes = @"{ ""visibility"": ""SiteMapPathHelper,!*"" }")]
```

NOTE: If you need to supply multiple custom attributes, separate them with a comma.

```
Attributes = @"{ ""visibility"": ""SiteMapPathHelper,!*"", ""myCustomAttribute"": true }"
```

Comment: This worked. How can I specify attributes for the Root node? That has to be in the XML config.

Comment: If you set the [MvcSiteMapProvider_EnableSitemapsXml](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Configuring-MvcSiteMapProvider#mvcsitemapprovider_enablesitemapsxml) setting to false, you can use `MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute` for the home page and remove the `Mvc.sitemap` file (and `MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd` file) from the project.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do this is to create several custom visibility providers.  For example, if your visibility flag could be 'true' and 'false'....then you would simply make a visiblity provider that always returned false.  In the sitemapnodes you create in code - specify that provider.

If you do not want to do that on every attribute, make a new class that inherits from MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute that sets the proper visibility provider - then use that where appropriate.

Comment: Yeah that was the approach I took in the end. Thanks